# Draw Text on a generated Sprite object as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Everyone, I'm just a beginner and I have question. The idea of my program is that when the user clicks a button a circle is generated and it should be counting for each additional circle it should look something like this :

[image]

The number should be in center and I should be able to move the object with the number together this is my code:

```
add_s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,new_sond);


function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(400, 300, 25);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    this.addChild(btn);


}

//----------------------------Drag And Drop----------------------
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownH);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpH);

function mouseDownH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var object = evt.target;
    object.startDrag();
}

function mouseUpH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var obj = evt.target;
        obj.stopDrag();
}
```

I will be very thankful if someone can help me. 
How do i make the text to apear on the center of the circles and i still will be able to move them with the text

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: Add a TextField object to your `btn` sprite, and alter its text. Should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Vesper should have posted as an answer :)

Add a [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) object to your `Sprite`. Since the `TextField` is a child of the `Sprite`, it will move w/the `Sprite`. All you need to do is position the text in the middle of the circle:

```
function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(400, 300, 25);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    var textField = new TextField();
    textField.text = "1";
    textField.width = textField.textWidth; // default width is 100
    textField.height = textField.textHeight;
    textField.x = (25 - textField.textWidth)/2; // center it horizontally
    textField.y = (25 - textField.textHeight)/2; // center it vertically
    btn.addChild(textField);
    this.addChild(btn);
}
```

Note, as suggested by @Joeson Hwang, you could use a `Shape` object instead of a `Sprite` to draw the circles. The `Shape` is more lightweight than a `Sprite`. However, since `Shape` does not extend `DisplayObjectContainer`, you cannot add child objects to a `Shape` like you can with a `Sprite`.

@Joeson Hwang's answer suggests to add the `Shape` and the text to a `Sprite`. But that won't be saving you anything, so just draw the graphics directly to the `Sprite` as you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

use btn:Shape (saves a lot of system resources). and then put the Shape and your text into a Sprite. You could also add a Sprite into another Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [**flash.text.engine**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/engine/package-detail.html) package:

```
function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(cx, cy, cr);
    btn.graphics.endFill();

    // Font format
    var fontDescription:FontDescription = new FontDescription("Arial"); 
    var format:ElementFormat = new ElementFormat(fontDescription, 16, 0x000088);        

    // Display text
    var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement('1', format); 

    var textBlock:TextBlock = new TextBlock(); 
    textBlock.content = textElement; 

    // New display object containing text
    var textLine:TextLine = textBlock.createTextLine(null, 500); 

    // Centers the text inside the circle
    textLine.x = cx + (cr - textLine.width) / 2;
    textLine.y = cy + (cr - textLine.height) / 2;       

    // Add text into button
    btn.addChild(textLine);

    this.addChild(btn);
}
```

More info about creating text: [Creating and displaying text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9dd7ed846a005b294b857bfa122bd808ea6-7fff.html) in [ActionScript 3.0 Developer’s Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/index.html)